# How to web scrape empty table data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
def proba():
    html_file = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.biznesradar.pl/wskazniki-zadluzenia/06N')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file, 'lxml')
    fields = [item['data-field'] for item in soup.find_all('tr', attrs = {'data-field': True})]
    row_data = []
    dict_of_list = {}
    for field in fields:
        for war in soup.find(attrs = {f'data-field': '{}'.format(field)}).find_all('td', class_ = 'h'):
            [row_data.append(float(i.text.replace(' ', ''))) for i in war.find_all('span', class_ = 'value')]            
    for field in enumerate(fields):       
        dict_of_list["zadl_{}".format(field[1])] = np.array_split(row_data, len(fields))[field[0]].astype(np.float)
```

I would like to scrape this empty table data as None or np.nan to have equal rows in scraped data:
[image]
Html looks like this:
[image]

When i look for a no existing attrribute for example like this:
`x = soup.find(attrs = {f'data-field': 'LDER'}).tr`, python return NoneType object so i tried this condition:

```
[row_data.append(float(i.text.replace(' ', ''))) if war.span is not None else row_data.append(np.nan) for i in war.find_all('span', class_ = 'value')]
```

but it's not working properly :(.
Any ideas?

Comment: It's "scrape", not "scrap". To scrap something means to throw it away. Scrape = scraping. Scrap = scrapping.

Comment: Can you fix the identation in your code sample?

Answer (score 0):

```
dict_of_list = {}   
def proba():
    html_file = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.biznesradar.pl/wskazniki-zadluzenia/06N')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file, 'lxml')
    fields = [item['data-field'] for item in soup.find_all('tr', attrs = {'data-field': True})]
    row_data = []
    for field in fields:
        for war in soup.find(attrs = {f'data-field': '{}'.format(field)}).find_all('td', class_ = 'h'):
            if war.span is None:
                row_data.append(np.nan)
            else:
                row_data.append(float(war.span.text.replace(' ', '')))
    for field in enumerate(fields):       
        dict_of_list["zadl_{}".format(field[1])] = np.array_split(row_data, len(fields))[field[0]].astype(np.float)
```